# Adding multiple data catalog into one in kedro

Tags: kedro

I am dynamically creating pipeline, nodes and catalog for a project. After creating the them, I want to add pipelines and the catalogs. Adding the pipelines is possible by sum function, but it's not possible for data catalog. Is there any way where i can add all the data catalog?

Tried all update and add method in kedro

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions to handle your problem:

1. [add data catalog in Python with kedro API](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/data/data_catalog.html#configure-a-data-catalog) - possibility to create dynamic data catalog
2. [add data catalog by CLI](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/data/data_catalog.html#create-a-data-catalog-yaml-configuration-file-via-cli) - you can pass what you want to CLI